# Adding handler to button presses

Tags: java, button, awt, actionlistener, actionevent

I have many GUI forms with many buttons on each GUI form. I am wanting to detect when a user clicks on any of these buttons.

My question is this: Should I add code individually to each button, or can I cater to each button press by a public method that is called whenever a button is pressed? If I use a public method (that I would rather do), how does the method detect the button that called the function? Do the buttons have to be a public variable?

Currently I am using this code (that works, I am wondering if I can do it better):

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.out.println("You clicked the button");
        }});
```

Comment: *"I am wanting to detect when a user clicks on any of these buttons."*  Then you typically need to figure which button was pressed, in order to make the appropriate action.  For that reason it is typically considered better to use one `ActionListener` or `AbstractAction` per button/menu item.

Comment: Noting that the 1 question has now expanded to 3 questions:  It is best to limit it to one question per ..question.  And please don't forget to add a question mark..

Comment: see if ActionEvent can be used to get target . learn to work with sdk

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271924/how-to-implement-and-mantain-multiple-actionlistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I add code individually to each button, or can I cater to each
>   button press by a public method that is called whenever a button is
>   pressed?

To my mind (and sanity), I'd separate the action listeners/handlers.  Generally speaking it keeps the individual actions/code simple and to the point.

Each button/menu can have more then one action listener if need be.

I'd also take a look at the [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) API

> If I use a public method (that I would rather do), how does the method
>   detect the button that called the function? Do the buttons have to be
>   a public variable?

If your really keen to follow this method, you can pass the `ActionEvent` to it, which would contain a reference to the source of the action as well as the action command.

Personally, I wouldn't. These kind of methods are notoriously difficult to manage, maintain, debug and update